# Unable to remove parent div of dynamically created cards

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

I want to remove a Parent div using js or jquery but I am unable to do so because it is multiple cards made dynamically. Here is my code:

```
<?php
for($ter as $term)
{
   <div class="wrapper-newjoinee-custom">
      <div class="breadcrumbs joinee-firstchild">
         <h2 class="section-heading blue-bar">      
            <?php 
               echo $term->name;
            ?> 
         </h2>
      </div>            
      <div class="row-joinee">
         <?php echo $term->data; ?>
      </div>
   </div>
}
?>
```

main.js file:

```js
jQuery(document).live(function($) {
    if ( $('.row-joinee').text().length == 0 ) {
        // length is 0
        $('.row-joinee').closest(".wrapper-newjoinee-custom").remove();
    }
});
```

please help me to make display none of `wrapper-newjoinee-custom` class if `row-joinee` class is empty

Comment: What version of jquery are you using ? using .live is outdated

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$(".row-joinee").filter(
    function() { return $(this).text().trim() == ""})
    .closest(".wrapper-newjoinee-custom").hide()
```

This will hide those `.wrapper-newjoinee-custom` that has en empty `<div class="row-joinee">`

**Demo**

```js
$(".row-joinee").filter(function() { return $(this).text().trim() == ""}).closest(".wrapper-newjoinee-custom").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-newjoinee-custom">
  <div class="breadcrumbs joinee-firstchild">
    <h2 class="section-heading blue-bar">
      name
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row-joinee">
    data
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-newjoinee-custom">
  <div class="breadcrumbs joinee-firstchild">
    <h2 class="section-heading blue-bar">
      name im empty
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row-joinee"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-newjoinee-custom">
  <div class="breadcrumbs joinee-firstchild">
    <h2 class="section-heading blue-bar">
      name
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row-joinee">
    data
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Dungeon Then people update your question with the rendered html